# Unique index constraint not working in Phoenix app

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my Phoenix app I have my User model as follows:

```
defmodule MyApp.User do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :username, :string, unique: true
    field :email, :string, unique: true
    field :crypted_password, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(email password username)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  @doc """
  Creates a changeset based on the `model` and `params`.

  If no params are provided, an invalid changeset is returned
  with no validation performed.
  """
  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
    |> unique_constraint(:username)
    |> validate_format(:email, ~r/@/)
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 5)
  end
end
```

I also have the following migration:

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateUser do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:users) do
      add :email, :string
      add :username, :string
      add :crypted_password, :string

      timestamps
    end

    create unique_index(:users, [:email])
    create unique_index(:users, [:username])
  end
end
```

And I have my `registration_controller_ex` as follows:

```
defmodule MyApp.RegistrationController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller
  alias MyApp.User

  def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{})
    render conn, changeset: changeset
  end

  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)

    if changeset.valid? do
      user = MyApp.Registration.create(changeset, MyApp.Repo)
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Your account was created")
      |> redirect(to: "/")
    else
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Unable to create account")
      |> render("new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
end
```

So, with all that I'm pretty sure my `username` and `email` fields in User are unique indexes. I also make sure that they are unique by calling `unique_constraint` to validate User.changeset. However, when in my interface I create a user with the same email and username as a preivously created one, the changeset is validated and the user is "created". (it's not actually created, when I look into the database nothing is added)

I get the following on my server logs, but my changeset.valid? is true.

```
[debug] BEGIN [] OK query=139.3ms queue=8.2ms
[debug] INSERT INTO "users" ("crypted_password", "email", "inserted_at", "updated_at", "username") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id" ["$2b$12$MN1YxFUGLMIJYXseZn0sjuuVs9U1jRdYtRr9D8XQsAqdh.D2sRRXa", "email@gmail.com", {{2015, 9, 30}, {11, 7, 25, 0}}, {{2015, 9, 30}, {11, 7, 25, 0}}, "username"] ERROR query=5.5ms
[debug] ROLLBACK [] OK query=0.4ms
```

Also, other things that I look for in my User.changeset function (such as minimum password length and other things) get reported to the user and are working just fine. It's just the unique indexes for `:email` and `:username` that are failing to be reported.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `unique_constraint` will be checked by the database and thus only be triggered upon inserting the record. Calling `changeset.valid?` will not check constraints and thus in this case return true. You need to check the return tuple of the Repo insert and act on that like:

```
def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
  changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)
  case  MyApp.Repo.insert changeset do
    {:ok, changeset} -> 
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Your account was created")
      |> redirect(to: "/")      
    {:error, changeset} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Unable to create account")
      |> render("new.html", changeset: changeset)      
  end
end
```

now your `changeset.errors` is enriched and you should be able to fetch the error with `changeset.errors[:email]`

Comment: It didn't work. I have a issue: registration_controller.ex:15: function changeset/0 undefined

Comment: For posterity the line above should be changed slightly: changset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)